# I have 2 tables in SQL server which I want top pivot such that a new column is created as soon as one table gets updated

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently, I am doing it this way:

```
WITH PivotData AS

    (
    SELECT 
           [acctrefno]
          ,LSC.status_code
          ,1  AS Qty
      FROM [NLS].[dbo].[loanacct_statuses] LS
      INNER JOIN loan_status_codes LSC ON LSC.status_code_no = LS.status_code_no
    )
    SELECT acctrefno, [120 DPD], 
    [150 DPD],
    [180 DPD],
    [30 DPD],
    [60 DPD],
    [90 DPD],


    FROM PivotData
    PIVOT( SUM(Qty) FOR Status_code IN([120 DPD], 
    [150 DPD],
    [180 DPD],
    [30 DPD],
    [60 DPD],
    [90 DPD],
    )) AS P
```

But the problem is the column names are hardcoded can you please help to make this SQL query such that whenever I have a new status_code imported it will automatically create a new column to Pivot.
i.e. I do not want to write the names of the column in the query.

Thank you in advance for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you are limited to **Dynamic SQL**.

There is a potential issue... that is the the sequence of columns, note the `order by DaysPastDue`  This is a placeholder for a proper sequence.

**Example (clearly not tested as there was no sample data supplied)**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
 From (
        SELECT [acctrefno]
              ,LSC.status_code
              ,1  AS Qty
          FROM [NLS].[dbo].[loanacct_statuses] LS
          JOIN loan_status_codes LSC ON LSC.status_code_no = LS.status_code_no
      ) A
 Pivot (sum([Qty]) For [status_code] in (' + stuff((Select ','+QuoteName(status_code) 
                                                     From  (Select Distinct 
                                                                   status_code 
                                                              From loan_status_codes 
                                                             Order by DaysPastDue Desc 
                                                           ) A
                                                     For XML Path('')),1,1,'')  + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
--Print @SQL
```